# Is it possible to list all the ContentWorkspaces (including private ones) using admin token with 'Query All Files' perms?

Tags: api, rest, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

As a system administrator, I want to fetch all the libraries from my organization. To achieve my goal I tried to use the request to `GET /services/data/v48.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+ContentWorkspace`.
But I did not get private 'ContentWorkspaces'.

Another problem that I faced was trying to create a file in user`s private library.

**Example 1**

```
POST /services/data/v48.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/


--boundary_string
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_content";
Content-type: application/json

{"PathOnClient":"FILE.txt", "OwnerId":"0051v000006lmLuAAI", "FirstPublishLocationId":"0581v000000dacWAAQ"}

--boundary_string
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="VersionData"; filename="FILE.txt"

Binary data goes here.

--boundary_string--
```

[image]

**Example 2**

```
POST /services/data/v48.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/


--boundary_string
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_content";
Content-type: application/json

{"PathOnClient":"FILE.txt", "OwnerId":"0051v000006lmLuAAI"}

--boundary_string
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="VersionData"; filename="FILE.txt"

Binary data goes here.

--boundary_string--
```

[image]

Is it possible to achieve everything that I mentioned above using the system admin token with 'Query All Files' perms or it is impossible?